# cannot connect to Database - No database selected Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel

I have been struggling to make this working for past hour or so.

I am getting an error when I am trying to execute a query in laravel.

Exact error is as below:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:272
Stack trace:
#0 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(272): PDO->prepare('select count(*)...')
#1 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(521): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), 'select count(*)...', Array)
#2 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(277): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select count(*)...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(1028): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select count(*)...', Array)
#4 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(1018): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#5 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(1005): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->getFresh(Array)
#6 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(1369): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#7 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(1311): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->aggregate('count', Array)
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->count()
#9 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(786): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 D:\www\testapp\app\routes.php(67): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('count', Array)
#11 D:\www\testapp\app\routes.php(67): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->count()
#12 [internal function]: {closure}()
#13 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(80): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#14 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(47): Illuminate\Routing\Route->callCallable()
#15 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1016): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(574): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 D:\www\testapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(550): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 D:\www\testapp\public\index.php(50): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#19 {main}
```

my config/database.php is as below:

```
'connections' => array(

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'testdatabase',
        'username'  => 'MYUSER',
        'password'  => 'MYPASSWORD',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

),
```

the code that triggers this error is:

```
 $users = DB::table('users')->get();
 print_r($users . "users");
```

can someone please help, I checked privileges for the given MySQL user, I also tried it with root account but to no avail so far.

Comment: Are you sure that specified database exists?

Comment: try 127.0.0.1 once as host

Comment: Do you have *'default' => 'mysql'*, above *'connections' => array(* ... ?

Comment: its really strange, I just setup a completely new laravel setup and asked it to connect to same database with same details and it works. It fetches the result. I wonder what is the problem with the other setup. @marcanuy yes, I do have that on the top of the file

Comment: maybe database driver files not downloaded correctly

Comment: Do you work in production environment? What you have in bootstrap/start.php file near line with `$env = $app->detectEnvironment`

Comment: @Tom I have following in bootstrap/start.php
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
 'local' => array(''),
 'staging' => array('test.somedomain.co.uk'),
 'production' => array('test.somedomain.co.uk'),
));

Comment: I think there might be a problem with env conflicts - try commenting out all custom environments from this file, leave `detectEnvironment` method empty and try if it connects

Comment: Ok found the problem, Thanks to @Tom.

It was indeed a Environment problem

First I printed my current environment by using the code 'echo App::environment();'

Then I went to that environment folder within config/{environment}/database.php file and modified the database details in this file which made everything worked. Thanks all.

Comment: As I suspected :) I wrote an answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an environment problem.

Put your `database.php` configuration file in `config/{environment}/database.php` then check if env is properly defined in `bootstrap/start.php` file and it should work.

To check what's your current env, run:

```
echo App::environment();
```